# How can I make numbers right adjusted?

Tags: java

How could I make some numbers right justified? I don't understand. I'm really new to Java. :-/
For example whenever I try to make this code right justified it gives me errors. 
Here is some sample code I found:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class JFindAlphabete
{
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in                                                      );

public static void main(String[] Theory)
{

    JWaffles MyWaffles = new JWaffles();

    MyWaffles.ProgramHeading();

    System.out.println("Enter a string:"                                                                                     );
    String SentenceContents = sc.nextLine(                                                                                   );

    int SpaceCount       = SentenceContents.length() - SentenceContents.replaceAll(" ", "").length(                          );
    int VowelCount       = SentenceContents.length() - SentenceContents.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "").length(                );
    int ConsonantCount   = SentenceContents.length() - SentenceContents.replaceAll("(?i)(?=[a-z])[^aeiou]", "").length(      );
    int SpecialCharCount = SentenceContents.length() - SentenceContents.replaceAll("(?i)[^a-z ]", "").length(                );
    int WordCount        = SentenceContents.trim().split("\\s+").length;




    System.out.println("There are " + VowelCount + " vowels in this sentance"                  );
    System.out.println("There are " + ConsonantCount + " consonants in this sentance"          );
    System.out.println("There are " + SpaceCount + " spaces in this sentance"                  );
    System.out.println("There are " + SpecialCharCount + " special characters in this sentance");
    System.out.println("There are " + WordCount + " words in this sentance"                    );






}
}
```

Comment: It "gives you errors"? Perhaps describing the nature of the errors would help ;) Also, you should be able to right justify using printf/format.

Comment: @fvu Meant printf, phone auto-corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.out`'s [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method instead of `println`, and use formatting options to right-adjust the values that you print:

```
System.out.printf("There are %5d vowels in this sentance\n"     , VowelCount);
System.out.printf("There are %5d consonants in this sentance\n" , ConsonantCount);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.out.format` class with, for instance, `System.out.format("There are %2d vowels in this sentence", vowelCount)` You can read a good tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

It allows you to print according to a predefined format, including fixed width numbers (with space padding).

It's probably the closest you'll get to 'right-justifying' these numbers.